# How to use ST_CONTAINS in Spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a fully working server serving random articles, saved within a MySQL database and I want to make it possible to find articles within a polygon.

I discovered that MySQL already supports `Polygon` and `Point` so I just used `ST_CONTAINS`, which is also supported. As articles do have an embedded latitude and longitude, I thought I could create a point and try finding out if it is contained in the polygon.

```java
import org.springframework.data.geo.Polygon;

// ...I pass the JPA declaration...

@Query("SELECT an " +
       "FROM Announce as an " +
       "WHERE ST_CONTAINS(?1, Point(an.latLng.longitude, an.latLng.latitude))")
List<Announce> findAllInPolygon(Polygon polygonPoints);
```

I don't see an error, but at runtime, I get a fatal error:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 80 [SELECT an FROM com.desoftmotion.findnow.domain.Announce 
as an WHERE ST_CONTAINS(POLYGON(?1), Point(an.latLng.longitude, an.latLng.latitude))]
```

Which I don't understand, as I thought `ST_CONTAINS` was known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found out that `ST_CONTAINS` should be compared to `true`. Something like

```java
@Query("SELECT an "
       "FROM Announce as an " +
       "WHERE true = ST_CONTAINS(?1, Point(an.latLng.longitude, an.latLng.latitude))")
```

It worked for me, though I don't have any result.

Moreover, the `Point` even if it's understood by MySQL, it comes out not be well mapped by JPA. So I've concatenated like

`GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', an.latLng.longitude, ' ', an.latLng.latitude, ')'))`

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess:

```
@Query("SELECT an.<col_name> " +  -- here should be column name, not a table alias
       "FROM Announce as an " +
       "WHERE ST_CONTAINS(?1, Point(an.latLng.longitude, an.latLng.latitude))")
```